# scoped_lock doesn't work on file?

Tags: boost

According to the link below, I wrote a small test case. But it doesn't work. Any idea is appreciated!

Reference:
http://www.cppprog.com/boost_doc/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.file_lock.file_lock_careful_iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>

using namespace std; 
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main()
{
    ofstream file_out("fileLock.txt");
    file_lock f_lock("fileLock.txt");

    {
        scoped_lock<file_lock> e_lock(f_lock);  // it works if I comment this out
        file_out << 10;
        file_out.flush();
        file_out.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get compiler errors? Assertions at runtime? Unexpected behavior? Give some details.

Comment: It compiles but during runtime, it doesn't write into fileLock.txt.

Comment: I can reproduce that with VC++ 2010 SP1 and boost 1.46.1. You should probably post this on the boost users mailing list, as it appears to be a bug given that the exact sample code in the documentation fails to work.

Comment: reproduced on windows 7 with MINGW so it does not seem to be a visual C++ thing. I will give it a try with on Linux in the morning

Comment: +1 for providing a short, complete, compilable test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running the test on Linux produces your desired output. I notice these two warnings:

The page you reference has this warning: "If you are using a std::fstream/native file handle to write to the file while using file locks on that file, don't close the file before releasing all the locks of the file."

`Boost::file_lock` apparently uses `LockFileEx` on Windows. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has this to say: "If the locking process opens the file a second time, it cannot access the specified region through this second handle until it unlocks the region."

It seems like, on Windows at least, the file lock is per-handle, not per-file. As near as I can tell, that means that your program is guaranteed to fail under Windows.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I think I will post it to boost users mailing list later. Please comment if you have new ideas about this test case.

Answer (score 4):

Your code appears to be susceptible to this long-standing bug on the boost trac site: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2796

The title of that bug is "**interprocess::file_lock has incorrect behavior when win32 api is enabled**".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to append in a file with a file locking based on Boost 1.44.

```
#include "boost/format.hpp"
#include "boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp"

namespace ip = boost::interprocess;
namespace ipc = boost::interprocess::detail;

void fileLocking_withHandle()
{
  static const string filename = "fileLocking_withHandle.txt";  

  // Get file handle
  boost::interprocess::file_handle_t pFile = ipc::create_or_open_file(filename.c_str(), ip::read_write);
  if ((pFile == 0 || pFile == ipc::invalid_file()))
  {
    throw runtime_error(boost::str(boost::format("File Writer fail to open output file: %1%") % filename).c_str());
  }

  // Lock file
  ipc::acquire_file_lock(pFile);

  // Move writing pointer to the end of the file
  ipc::set_file_pointer(pFile, 0, ip::file_end);

  // Write in file
  ipc::write_file(pFile, (const void*)("bla"), 3);

  // Unlock file
  ipc::release_file_lock(pFile);

  // Close file
  ipc::close_file(pFile);
}
```